# How do I prove: the posterier is proportional to the product of the prior distribution and the likelihood function?

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability

In the book of *pattern recognition and machine learning* equation (1.66) says:

> ```
> Using Bayes’ theorem, the posterior distribution $\bf{w}$ for is proportional 
> to the product of the prior distribution and the likelihood function.
> ```

$$
p(\bf{w}|\bf{x},\bf{t}, \alpha, \beta) \propto p(\bf{t}|\bf{w},\bf{x}, \beta) p(\alpha|\bf{w})
$$

I do know that Bayes's theorem is $P(A,B)=P(A|B)P(B)=P(B|A)P(A)$ but I don't quite know how to derive this so many variable case. Besides, what is the proportion constant, why the remaining is a constant?

Comment: Is there any dependence/independence between variables?

Comment: @CarlosCampos It seems that $\bf{x}$ and $\bf{t}$ are datat, $\alpha$ is the parameter of the prior probability and $\beta$ is the variance of the Gaussian distribution